# What does "Auto" mean for Visual Studio Unit Test Runner Bitness?

Tags: c#, 64-bit, mstest, visual-studio-2022

This is about the following Visual Studio 2022 menu option:

- Test/Processor Architecture for AnyCPU Projects/Auto.

**What exactly does "Auto" mean?**

[image: Screenshot]

Background: We recently had the case where the same C# MSTest unit test project ran as x86 on one dev's PC and as x64 on another dev's PC, both set to Auto and both running x64 Windows. This sparked our curiosity, and we'd like to understand what that menu option means exactly. If tried to check the documentation, but couldn't find anything official online.

Comment: When auto-detecting, the architecture for AnyCPU DLLs may differ based on the runner. For .NET Framework runner (in Visual Studio, or vstest.console.exe in Developer command line), the default is x86. For .NET runner (dotnet test), the default is the current process architecture. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2022#runconfiguration-element

Comment: @shingo: This sounds like "Auto" actually means "I don't care, just use whatever is easier for the test runner". :-)